# Easier way to change all the buttons?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, background-color

I have 10 `UIButton`s that I want to change the background color of.

Here's what I have right now:

```
b1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b3.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b4.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b5.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b6.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b7.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b8.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b9.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b10.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

I wonder if there is another, simpler, way of doing this. I have all ready tried `UIButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]` but that didn't work.

Comment: The reason that your last attempt doesn't work is that the class (`UIButton`) is a different object and does not serve as a "template" object for its instances. When using your last approach, the language tries to set the property `backgroundColor` on the class, and classes don't have background colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Make an array of the buttons:
NSArray* buttons=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,nil];
//Loop through them
for(UIButton* b in buttons)
{
  b.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

The array could also be initialized in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2):

Put the buttons in an array:

```
NSArray* buttonArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,nil];
```

Then set the background color for all the buttons:

```
[buttonArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Cool method! I did the more C-like approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your buttons in `viewDidLoad`. Then just use a for loop to change colors.